# Button onclick changing colour following a situation not working. C# unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Sorry for the simultaneous question, just this one has been griping me for a while.

Back onto these 4 button things (following the last post), I wanted them to go green following a 'correct click'. So if one person clicked the right button, it would go green.

Originally, I decided to make 4 variables and set them to 'y' and 'n'. If the user clicked the right button it would go 'y', which would then lead to the corresponding object to go 'green', and so forth.
However, when I did this all of the buttons go green. Following a debug check, they all go green following one correct answer, which has me thinking that they are somehow connected (in a way I do not understand).

Here is the code I used:

```
void Update () {
    Image image = GameObject.Find("Answer1").GetComponent<Image>();
    Image image2 = GameObject.Find("Answer2").GetComponent<Image>();
    Image image3 = GameObject.Find("Answer3").GetComponent<Image>();
    Image image4 = GameObject.Find("Answer4").GetComponent<Image>();
    if (randQuestion == -1)
    {
        randQuestion = Random.Range(0, 5);
    }

    if (randQuestion > -1)
    {
        GetComponent<Text>().text = questions[randQuestion];
    }

    if (choiceSelected == "y")
    {
        choiceSelected = "n";

        if (correctAnswer[randQuestion] == buttonSelected)
        {
            Debug.Log("Correct!");

            if (Answer1script.answerCorrect1 == "y")
            {
                image.color = Color.green;
            }

            if (Answer2script.answerCorrect2 == "y")
            {
                image2.color = Color.green;
            }

            if (Answer3script.answerCorrect3 == "y")
            {
                image3.color = Color.green;
            }

            if (Answer4script.answerCorrect4 == "y")
            {
                image4.color = Color.green;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have obviously done something wrong; any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: For starters you should move initialization of `image` variables from `Update` to `Start` method. Also you should move all other code from `Update` to some custom method and call it when buttons are clicked. `Update` is called once per  frame (many times every second).

Comment: Okay, that makes sense! Just, assuming I do that, how to I make it so that when buttons are clicked it does something?

Comment: Check the onClick UnityEvent on the Button component. Either use the inspector, or use code to register to AddListener. Best is to check the Button tutorial in unity learn page.